# The Matrix Winds In

Tags: java, algorithm, array

The Problem: Given an N by M Matrix, Create an Anti-Clockwise Traversal Path that winds in all the way into the Matrix

Example: The Matrix is 9 by 5

Output:

```
|  1|| 24|| 23|| 22|| 21|
|  2|| 25|| 40|| 39|| 20|
|  3|| 26|| 41|| 38|| 19|
|  4|| 27|| 42|| 37|| 18|
|  5|| 28|| 43|| 36|| 17|
|  6|| 29|| 44|| 35|| 16|
|  7|| 30|| 45|| 34|| 15|
|  8|| 31|| 32|| 33|| 14|
|  9|| 10|| 11|| 12|| 13|
```

Code:

```
package com.progint;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.SecureRandom; /*For Maximum-Entropy Goodness*/

public class DerLooper {
    static final int xMax=20, yMax=20,  xMin=1, yMin=1; /* Maximum and Minimum Matrix Size */
    static int xCord, yCord;
    static SecureRandom randomGenerator = new SecureRandom();
    static int[][] looper;
    
    DerLooper() {
        xCord= xMin+randomGenerator.nextInt(xMax-xMin); yCord=yMin+randomGenerator.nextInt(yMax-yMin); 
        looper = new int[xCord][yCord];
    }
    
    /*
     *      ________left__________    
     *     |                     |
     *   down                    up
     *     |_______right_________|
     *     
     *     right eats higher row 
     *     up eats higher column
     *     left eats lower row
     *     down eats lower column
     * 
     */
    static void displayLooper() {
        int pathNumber=1;
        int currentX=0, currentY=0;
        int lowerColumn=0, lowerRow=0;
        int higherColumn=yCord, higherRow=xCord;
        while(true) {
            //Go Down if Possible
            /*   
             *    0
             * 0 [1]
             * 1 [2]
             * 2 [3]
             * 3 [4]
             *  higherColumn,lowerColumn=0 | lowerRow=0,higherRow=3
             */
            while(currentX<higherRow) {
                looper[currentX++][currentY] = pathNumber++;
            }
            if(lowerColumn+1<higherColumn)  {lowerColumn++;} //eats lower column
            else if (lowerColumn+1>=higherColumn) {break;}
            
            //Go Right if Possible
            /*   
             *    0  1  2  3  4
             * 0 [1]
             * 1 [2]
             * 2 [3]
             * 3 [4][5][6][7][8]
             *  higherColumn=4,lowerColumn=1 | lowerRow=0,higherRow=3
             */
            currentX--;
            currentY++;
            while(currentY<higherColumn) {
                looper[currentX][currentY++] = pathNumber++;
            }
            if(higherRow-1>lowerRow)  {higherRow--;} //eats higher row
            else if (higherRow-1<=lowerRow) {break;}
            
            
            //Go Up if Possible
            /*   
             *    0  1  2  3   4
             * 0 [1]         [11]
             * 1 [2]         [10]
             * 2 [3]          [9]
             * 3 [4][5][6][7][8]
             *  higherColumn=4,lowerColumn=1 | lowerRow=0,higherRow=2
             */
            currentX--;
            currentY--;
            while(currentX>=lowerRow) {
                looper[currentX--][currentY] = pathNumber++;
            }       
            if(higherColumn-1>lowerColumn)  {higherColumn--;} //eats higher column
            else if (higherColumn-1<=lowerColumn) {break;}
            
            //Go Left if Possible
            /*   
             *    0    1   2   3    4
             * 0 [1]  [14][13][12] [11]
             * 1 [2]               [10]
             * 2 [3]               [9]
             * 3 [4]  [5] [6] [7]  [8]
             *  higherColumn=3,lowerColumn=1 | lowerRow=0,higherRow=2
             */
            currentX++;
            currentY--;
            while(currentY>=lowerColumn) {
                looper[currentX][currentY--] = pathNumber++;
            }       
            if(lowerRow+1<higherRow) {lowerRow++;} //eats lower row     
            else if (lowerRow+1>=higherRow) {break;}
    
            //Loop through next subMatrix
            /*   
             *    0    1   2   3    4
             * 0 [1]  [14][13][12] [11]
             * 1 [2]  here         [10]
             * 2 [3]               [9]
             * 3 [4]  [5] [6] [7]  [8]
             *  higherColumn=3,lowerColumn=1 | lowerRow=1,higherRow=2
             */
             currentX++;    
             currentY++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("The Matrix is "+xCord+" by "+yCord+"\n");
        for (int i=0; i<xCord; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<yCord; j++) {  
                System.out.printf("|%3d|",looper[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        new DerLooper();
        displayLooper();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We see multiple code stanzas that resemble:

```
            currentX--;
            currentY++;
```

which seems tedious.

Define a vector of four (delta_x, delta_y) pairs:
`{(0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0)}`
and iterate through the vector.

Comment: Definitely contracts, but also affects the readability of an already boundary-case cursed algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand your remark. Let's say we can conveniently compute `point + delta`, for a delta of unit magnitude. And we break out an `is_valid_coord(...)` predicate. Then it's a matter of asking whether `is_valid_coord(point + delta)`, and keep bumping the delta index while it's invalid. You could combine "valid?" with "visited?" in a single predicate if you like. If you cycle through 4 directions without making any progress, then you have arrived at the omphalos and you're done.